# Cant use lua LSP in neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

I installed this config for NeoVim: https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch , and when i open some .lua or another file the message below says 'Client 2 quit with exit code 127 and signal 0'

I tired to reinstall servers and config,  and afterwards looked at :LspLog

> [START][2023-03-29 20:33:49] LSP logging initiated
>
> [ERROR][2023-03-29 20:33:49] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:733 "rpc" "lua-language-server" "stderr"  "/data/data/        com.termux/files/home/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/lua-language-server: line 3: /data/data/com.termux/        files/home/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/lua-language-server/extension/server/bin/lua-language-server: cannot execute: required file not found\n"

what should i do here?

Answer (score 2):

- Change you sumneko_lua server to lua_ls in the ~/.config/nvim/lua/user/lsp/mason.lua because sumneko_lua is depricated,actually they have not updated yet
- Or if you want have better understanding you can you use my config as refrence which is based on nvim-basic-ide config but it is upto date.
- My [configs link](https://github.com/sadikeey/nvim).
- And also let know if your issue got fixed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help, i fixed my problem by uninstalling sumneko_lua from Mason and installing lua_language_server from my package manager (pkg in termux).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to install `lua-language-server` in termux:

```bash
apt update
apt install lua-language-server
```

And then create a symbolic link to that server:

```bash
ln -f -s "$(command -v lua-language-server)" /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/lua-language-server/libexec/bin/lua-language-server
```

If you have a problem with the configuration not recognizing the Neovim library, there is this configuration that I found on NvChad, but in your case it may be already configured by LunarVim:

```lua
require("lspconfig").lua_ls.setup {
  on_attach = M.on_attach,
  capabilities = M.capabilities,

  settings = {
    Lua = {
      diagnostics = {
        globals = { "vim" },
      },
      workspace = {
        library = {
          [vim.fn.expand "$VIMRUNTIME/lua"] = true,
          [vim.fn.expand "$VIMRUNTIME/lua/vim/lsp"] = true,
          [vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/lazy/ui/nvchad_types"] = true,
          [vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy"] = true,
        },
        maxPreload = 100000,
        preloadFileSize = 10000,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

> Remember to adapt this configuration according to your plugin manager, in my case I'm using Lazy which I already saw on NvChad

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error, but it was caused by the lua-language-server binary needing dynamically linked libraries that weren't available by default in nixos which I'm using.

This guide provides a pretty good workaround to this problem using nix-ld.

https://nix.dev/guides/faq.html#how-to-run-non-nix-executables

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35750195)

Answer (score 0):

To jump straight  to solution, scroll down to the solution part.

**Background**

I installed NixOS on October 2023, coming from Ubuntu 20.04, with neovim as my default text editor and Personal Development Environment.

So, everything on my neovim inside a fresh NixOS should go back to normal... right? Well, it didn't. That's why I'm here.

**The LSP problem**

Ever since the debut of NixOS on my laptop, lua-language-server (lua language server) never worked. I tried everything; a different version of Lua, installation of luaJIT; I even reset packer a couple of times (maybe I downloaded a corrupt version of lspconfig?), and reinstall all plugins, NOTHING worked. The following is a list of LSPs that didn't work (there may be more!):

- Lua-Language-Server (luals)
- rust-analyzer
- clangd (for c/c++)

So I came into terms that I may not enjoy the ravishes of auto-completions for Lua, as theprimeagen highly praised it (who is definitely not working for Netflix); and for the other above languages. This went on until a happy accident occurred.

**The accident**

Fast forward to March 2024, while fooling around with `sudo chown -R -755 .`, I accidentally ran it while on my home directory. I was immediately hit with negative effects; notifications on some apps crashing, permission denied while running apps; it was mayhem all over. While I knew I could get by, by restoring some permissions; for my laptop to be back to absolute normal, I believed I had to reinstall NixOS. So I did just that.

**Tiny light in a sea of regrets**

After coming into terms that I will lose about a day to return my laptop into its former glory, I backed up my nix and home configurations, then reinstalled NixOS. Then overwritten the default nix config with mine truly and did the classic `sudo nix-channel --update && sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` and copied my configurations back to home directory.

After it completed, I opened up neovim. After packer initializations and installations, I reopened again, this time opening neovim configuration folder  with `cd ~/.config/nvim && nvim .`

Oooooh! I couldn't believe it! lua-language-server spun to life, indexing the nvim folder! highlighting every file with error on nvim-tree float window. On that moment, all the regrets poofed away.

**But.. how?**

While exasperating lua-language-server with bunch of erroneous codes, this question kept bugging me at the back of my head, how could it be? What happened different this time? Can we replicate it again? We should definitely try to replicate this.

"If it works don't touch it! or will break!" I tried to comfort myself.

More questions kept popping up: what if you restart and it doesn't work any more? What if you install something else and scrambles this precious "one-of-a-kind" setup?

"Aaargh! Now I have to figure out how this came to be!" I talked to myself.

**Lets go for a hunt then..**

So, where do we start? at neovim's `:Mason` of course. Let's reinstall lua-language-server and see if it will still be working.

"But, hey; there's no going back after this.." said to myself cautiously as I stared at the line highlighting lua-language-server on Mason popup. Hit `<S-x>` fast, uninstalled it; then navigated down and hit `i` for installation...

"Nothing! Nothing is working!" I yelled while banging the table angrily.

Yeah, But this time its different!

This time, we now know FOR SURE that lua-language-server CAN run on NixOS without any problems! my thoughts calmed me.

So, we know that lua-language-server was working, until we tried to reinstall it. Safe to say that Mason is the culprit here.

**Solution (for lua-language-server and others alike)**

So I opened Mason configurations in neovim with `cd ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/ && nvim .`, navigated through `bin` directory on nvim-tree, and found lua-language-server softlink file. opened it:

```
        1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
        2
        3 exec "/packages/lua-language-server/libexec/bin/lua-language-server" "$@"
    ~
```

Then I remembered, the error: `lua-language-server: cannot execute: required file not found`

What if I change the file path here, as to a built in (installed via nixpkgs)?

Alas, I hopped into [search.nixos.org](https://search.nixos.org) and searched for `lua language server`, installed on my laptop with `nix-env -iA nixos.lua-language-server`

Then found out I had already installed it since I wrote it on my configuration.nix file, (that's why it worked on a brief moment, until I screwed it up)

I then ran `which lua-language-server` to confirm its local location. there after i ran `which lua-language-server | wl-copy` to copy the path to clipboard, and pasted to the file above. It now looked like this:

```
        1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
        2
        3 exec "/home/your-username/.nix-profile/bin/lua-language-server" "$@"
    ~
```

saved the file and exit with `:wq` and entered the neovim configuration folder again with `cd ~/.config/nvim && nvim .`

She's working once again!

lua-language-server has been working ever since.

**Solution (for rust-analyzer, clanigd and others alike)**

After successive solving of lua LSP, and recovered some wit on me; I decided to tackle rust-analyzer next. So I opened Mason configurations in neovim, once again with `cd ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/ && nvim .`, navigated through `bin` directory on nvim-tree, and hopped into rust-analyzer softlink file.

Uum, 45mb? what is in this file? yap, pure byte code ladies and gentlemen! No paths to swap here.

But, since this is a softlink file, we can create a new link to a new rust-analyzer installed with nixpkgs. This should work, right? one way to find out.

I dove into [search.nixos.org](https://search.nixos.org) and searched for `rust-analyzer`, installed on my laptop with `nix-env -iA nixos.rust-analyzer`
I, then ran `which rust-analyzer` to confirm its local location. There after I ran `which rust-analyzer | wl-copy` to copy the path to clipboard.

Then I renamed the existing rust-analyzer softlink file in the `bin` folder into rust-analyzer1

There after, I pasted the path on the terminal and construct a softlink command as follows (make sure you execute the below command while inside the `bin` folder of mason configuration):

run command: `ln --symbolic -T /home/your-username/.nix-profile/bin/rust-analyzer rust-analyzer`

After the above procedures, I had the following files in the `bin` folder:

[rust-analyzer and rust-analyzer1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVGbg.png)

There after, I closed neovim, and used neovim to open any rust file, and voila! rust-analyzer is chugging along, spitting out errors; uuhg, the burrow checker; nice to see you again.

**Post Script**

1. Summary: there 2 solution approaches to the LSP issue. depending on whether there is a path to executable inside softlink file or NOT, pick one of the approaches.
2. For the above 'patching' to work, you need to first install the LSPs through Mason. only then will you be able to successfully rip the fruits.
3. Do not update the patched LSP through Mason, as it will override it, get you back to zero LSPing.
4. I don't think that Mason is the culprit for all these "fiascos", he's just the easiest to trick IMO.